# Pig Schema to load the data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have Input data format as below to represent the out going links from a source URL i.e Source URL 1 has 2 and 3 outgoing URLs

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4
4 1
```

And I would like to load into Pig as below

```
N,  aN
(1,(2,3))
(2,(3,4))
(3,(4))
(4,(1))
```

Can I do this using default AS schema or Do I have to write a custom loader function.

Comment: Could you please explain what the columns in the input format mean? For the line `3 4` does this mean that 3 is only adjacent to 4 (assuming this is directed)?

Comment: I have edited the description about input format . {3 4} means 4 is outgoing link from 3.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a custom loader, or modify your data structure a tad.  Without a custom loader, you could get it into this format:

```
N,  aN
(1,(2,3))
(2,(3,4))
(,(3,4))
(,(4,1))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply . Previously my expected format was wrong , I have edited it . Could you please look into this again . Basically the first number in the line is source URL and rest are out going links from this source URL and they can be 1 to many .